# Command history for mira?

Tags: miranda

Does the mira command have a shell-like history mechanism for commands typed at the terminal?  I'm constantly hitting up-arrow to correct a minor typo, but it doesn't work.  I'm using Miranda 2.044 for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it does not seem so.

You can use $$ as shorthand for the last expression evaluated however, and !! for the last shell command.

See: https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/manual/5.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this Python 2 oneliner, which redirects standard input to Mira through a shell:

```
python -c "import readline,subprocess as s;p=s.Popen('mira',shell=True,stdin=s.PIPE);[p.stdin.write(raw_input()+'\n') for _ in iter(int,1)]"
```

It also allows you to use backspace to correct typos.

Alternatively, try the [rlwrap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) utility:

```
rlwrap mira
```